# How to copy zip file to remote server location using FileStream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, filestream

I'm trying to copy zip file to remote server location using file stream, below is my web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SavePackage(string args = "{}")
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\abc.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] byteData = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(byteData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
}
```

but I don't know how to write byteData to destination as a zip.

before I was using the `File.Copy` method but that is not working for remote server.

Comment: Are you able to open an output stream on that server?

Comment: if your file size if large. fs.length will give out of memory error. Try using buffers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching in many blogs, I have found we need some kind of client control which interacts with client machine. So I have used the shared path to upload that file to destination rather than some random path in my case "c:\temp\abc.zip".

Below is my WebMethod to do that task.

```
[WebMethod]
public string SavePackage(string args = "{}")
{
    try
    {
        // here i am accepting json args as parameter
        string sourcePath = string.Empty, type = string.Empty, category = string.Empty, description = string.Empty, additionalComments = string.Empty;
        var jsonargs = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(args);

        if (jsonargs.Count == 0)
        {
            return "{'message':'No parameters', 'status':'404'}";
        }

        foreach (var item in jsonargs)
        {
            sourcePath = (item.Key.ToLower() != "sourcepath" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourcePath)) ? sourcePath : item.Value.ToString().Replace(@"""", "").Replace(@"\\", @"\"); // shared path
            type = (item.Key.ToLower() != "type" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type)) ? type : item.Value.ToString().Replace(@"""", "");
            category = (item.Key.ToLower() != "category" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(category)) ? category : item.Value.ToString().Replace(@"""", "");
            description = (item.Key.ToLower() != "description" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)) ? description : item.Value.ToString().Replace(@"""", "");
            additionalComments = (item.Key.ToLower() != "additionalcomments" || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(additionalComments)) ? additionalComments : item.Value.ToString().Replace(@"""", "");
        }

        if (!Path.GetExtension(sourcePath).Equals(".zip"))
        {
            return "{'message':'File source path is not in a zip format', 'status':'404'}";
        }

        var filename = sourcePath.Remove(0, sourcePath.LastIndexOf("\\", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);    
        var tempDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);
        var destPath = Path.Combine(tempDir, filename);
        File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath, true);

        if (!File.Exists(destPath))
        {
            return "{'message':'File not copied', 'status':'404'}";
        }

        return "{'message':'OK', 'status':'200'}";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "{'message':'error', 'status':'404'}";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `logging` object declared in `SavePackage` method which you've used throughout your code. I doubt that this code will even compile.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (var outStream = new FileStream(somePath, FileMode.Write))
{
   using (var inStream = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Read))
   {
        inStream.CopyTo(outStream);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.File.Copy is ok, but the prerequisite is that your pc has right to access to the destination.

One of the most convenient way to verify is finding a network shared drive and then copy your file to there. 
i.e.

```
File.Copy(@"c:\temp\MyFile.txt", @"\\server\folder\Myfile.txt", true);
```

Comment: If you have admin credentials and **any** folder shared, you can use `@"\\server\c$\somefolder\anotherfolder\myfile.txt"` to copy it to `c:\somefolder\anotherfolder\myfile.txt` without having to share the folder.

Comment: Hi, Cid, you are right. But i wonder that if there is no right, could FileStream or any methods using System.IO write a file into remote server?

Comment: @NKLI I don't have share path so File.Copy won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use BinaryWriter. See this code:
first add this namespace: using System.IO

```
   var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("YOUR_SOURCE_PATH");

   BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("DESTINATION_PATH.zip"));

   writer.Write(bytes);
```

Consider when you read file data as byte array, there is no matter your file extension.

Comment: You can write `byte[]` directly to a stream, the BW adds nothing.

Comment: And for a big file you ought to break this up in blocks, using a while loop.

Comment: @saeed

`var docPath = sourcePath;
var filestream = new FileStream(docPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var len = (int)filestream.Length;
var document = new Byte[len];
filestream.Read(document, 0, len);

var destdocPath = destPath;
var objfilestream = new FileStream(destdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
objfilestream.Write(document, 0, document.Length);

Above code is giving me error
Could not find file 'C:\Temp\abc.zip'.`

I am using postman from my host machine to post the request.

Comment: @Naveen Kumar are you sure your file exist?

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani Yes it's exist on my client machine and providing the same client machine path to the WebMethod.